# excel xll :name of the calling function from within function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, excel, dll, xll

i have c++ xll program which is buit using the microsoft excel sdk. is there any excel4v() or excel12v() functions that can tell me the name of the excel user defined function that it is being called from.

for example say i have two excel user defined function my_func1() and my_func2(). say i have another function func() which is called by both my_func1() and my_func2().  inside func() i want to place this excel4v/excel12v function to determine which user defined function (my_func1() or my_func2()) is calling func(). is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Why not add a parameter to func and have my_func1 and my_func2 tell func who they are?
Why drag Excel4 into this?